# python Errno 22 shutil copy

Tags: python-3.x, windows

Estoy desarrollando un script en python 3.9, el cual luego de realizar unas tareas sobre unos archivos, procede a copiar a traves de la sentencia shutil.copy(origen, destino) varios de los archivos en cuestion..
El problema, esta que al momento de hacer la copia aparece un error que dice :

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\Temp\*.*'

La estructura de archivos la estoy probando directamente en mi maquina (con windows) y estaba originalmente en una carpeta que tiene directorios con espacios en blanco..

C:\Users\user\OneDrive - abcd\Escritorio\Clientes\SNSAT\DataMigration\conversion Radiometrica\IMAGENES DE MUESTRA SATELITAL\LANDSAT_5

pense que podria ser por dichos espacios en blanco, y cambie a :

C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\NotProcess\Radiometric

pero el problema persiste

Pense tb, que el comando copy estaba mal formulado, asi que imprimi los parametros de origen y destino

imagenOrigen  C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\Temp*.*
imagenDestino C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\

copie dichos parametros y los pegue en una ventana de cmd con el comando copy

copy C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\Temp*.* C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\

y desde el sistema operativo si se realiza la copia de los archivos (son 35)

Este es el codigo de mi script

```
# copiael temp, al directorio anterior
print("*******IINICIA COPIA DE IMAGEN********")
imagenOrigen = pathTemporal + "*.*"
imagenDestino = pathImagesBase + pathImagesOutPut + "\\" + Path(pathImagen).name + "\\"
print(f"imagenOrigen  {imagenOrigen}")
print(f"imagenDestino {imagenDestino}")

if shutil.copy(imagenOrigen, imagenDestino):
    print(f"copiar Archivo Imagen     = Archivo {imagenOrigen} copiado OK")                        
print("*******TERMINA COPIA DE IMAGEN********")
```

el ultimo print, nunca llega a ejecutarse y en la consola del vscode me aparece el siguiente error:

```
*******IINICIA COPIA DE IMAGEN********
imagenOrigen  C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\Temp\*.*
imagenDestino C:\AmbienteDesa\Satelites\LANDSAT-5\Process\Colecc2_level1\
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\abcd\lib\threading.py", line 973, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\abcd\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 205, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\abcd\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 381, in dispatch_events
    handler.dispatch(event)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\abcd\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 271, in dispatch
    self.on_any_event(event)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - ABCD  Chile\Escritorio\abcd\Clientes\Clientes\SNSAT\DataMigration\conversion Radiometrica\Scripts\ConversionRadiometricaV3.py", line 886, in on_any_event
    procesa_Grupo3(pathRecurso, self._datosConfig)
  File "C:\Users\user\OneDrive - ABCD Chile\Escritorio\Abcd\Clientes\Clientes\SNSAT\DataMigration\conversion Radiometrica\Scripts\ConversionRadiometricaV3.py", line 745, in procesa_Grupo3
    if shutil.copy(imagenOrigen, imagenDestino):
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\abcd\lib\shutil.py", line 427, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\user\.conda\envs\abcd\lib\shutil.py", line 264, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\\AmbienteDesa\\Satelites\\LANDSAT-5\\Process\\Colecc2_level1\\Temp\\*.*'
Terminando observador Conversion Radiometrica_Grupo3_LANDSAT-5
```

Alguna idea de porque esto no funciona?
Gracias por leer

Comment: que es exactamente lo que estas copiando? puede ser que se este usando el fichero en cuestion o algo por el estilo, o que no tengas permiso para eso. ademas cmoo recomendacion utiliza una shell de powershell para ejecutar tus scripts

Comment: `shutil.copy()` sólo copia un archivo a la vez. Tienes que darle el nombre.

Answer (score 1):

`shutil.copy` no copia cosas automáticamente, tienes que decirle qué va a copiar, dónde y con qué nombre. Por otro lado usa [os.path.join()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) para concatenar rutas y nombres de archivos, es menos propenso a errores y cross platform.

```
import os, shutil

dir_origen = r'C:\Directorio\De\Origen'
dir_destin = r'C:\Directorio\De\Destino'

os.makedirs(dir_destin, exist_ok=True) # Crea recursivamente el directorio, si no existe

for filename in os.listdir(dir_origen):
    src = os.path.join(dir_origen, filename)
    dst = os.path.join(dir_destin, filename)
    print(f'Moviendo {filename} --> {dir_destin}')
    shutil.copy2(src, dst)
```

Nota: [shutil.copy2](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) intenta preservar los metadatos (autor, fecha de creación, modificación, etc). Si no te interesa, puedes cambiarlo por `shutil.copy` normal.